# Getting y-axis shift during FFT noise removal

Tags: r, signal-processing, fft, ifft

I'm trying to do a noise removal by FFT in R. The trouble I'm having is that I get a y-axis shift during the process and I'm not sure what the cause is. I have read up on FFT and used [this resource as a guide](http://databaser.net/moniwiki/pds/_ed_91_b8_eb_a6_ac_ec_97_90_eb_b3_80_ed_99_98/Using_R_for_Smoothing_and_Filtering.pdf). See below for the code I have been executing as well as sample graphics of the result. Here is a dropbox link to the csv file. [data.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wdq923yuo36mgy/data.csv?dl=0)

```
data=read.csv('data.csv')
plot(data,type='l')

#FFT filtration function
fft.filter=function(data,threshold){
  temp=fft(data)
  temp[threshold:length(data)-threshold]=0+0i
  temp=Re(fft(temp,inverse=TRUE)/length(temp))
  return(temp)
}

data2=data
data2$Signal=fft.filter(data2$Signal,100)
```

**Unfiltered Plot:**
[image]

**Filtered Plot:**
[image]

As the images show, the data scaling looks fine, I'm just getting a shift that I don't think I should be. The FFT function is working to remove noise from the series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the indexing.  It is indexing from 0 to `length(data)-threshold`, whereas you want `threshold:(length(data)-threshold)` I believe.  Change the indexing line to

```
temp[threshold:(length(data)-threshold)]=0+0i
```